# Quiz App - How to displaying a varying number of answer options?

Tags: php

I have database table which contains a number of questions each with corresponding answer options (multiple choice question). I am able to use PHP to extract a single question (with answer options) from the database, and would like to display one question at a time with the corresponding answer options to the user.

In my index.php file, I show the user the question using:

```
<?php echo $question["questionText"]; ?>
```

And I show the answer options using:

```
<input type="radio" name="optradio" value="<?php echo $question["option1"]; ?> <?php echo $question["option1"]; ?>

<input type="radio" name="optradio" value="<?php echo $question["option2"]; ?>"> <?php echo $question["option2"]; ?>
```

My issue is that the number of answer options (which are in form of radio buttons) varies per question with a maximum of 9 options.

What is the best way of ensuring that the user sees only however many options they need to see?

Comment: Retrieve the all the answers to the question from your database, then loop through them creating a radio button for each one. Your question seems to therefore be 'how do I loop in PHP' to which there are already thousands of resources if you take the time to search for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of manually writing the below:

```
<input type="radio" name="optradio" value="<?php echo $question["option1"]; ?> <?php echo $question["option1"]; ?>
<input type="radio" name="optradio" value="<?php echo $question["option2"]; ?>"> <?php echo $question["option2"]; ?>
```

Just use a `foreach` loop here:

```
<?php foreach ($question as $option) { ?>
  <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="<?php echo $option; ?>"> <?php echo $option; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

You should really do the following:

1. Retrieve the answers from the database.
2. (Optionally) Store it in an array.
3. Loop through it.
4. Echo out each option.

The above method will be both dynamic (each question has the right number) and also the right way.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you!

Comment: @Adnan Happy that I could help you. Have a nice day mate! `:D`